# Video processing and hosting with API?

Tags: video, image-processing, video-streaming, cdn, video-processing

I am looking for a good provider of video hosting and processing with a API to let my users upload videos via PHP to them. It should be possible to stream the video resized if necessary like /video1234/400x600.

Currently I use Cloudinary but the servers are slow, who is the market leader in this field?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://aviapi.com. It's currently in beta and gives you **a full-featured 30 day free trial** to try. It looks like a new kid on the block but looks really promising. **aviApi** is an audio, video and image manipulation and processing API with a whole lot of features.
For audio and video, the tools that aviApi provides are extracting video and audio segments, extract video poster / thumbnail, resize video, rotate video. The filters that they provide are watermark video, video and audio slow motion / fast forward, mute video, extract audio from video. The API also allows to save one video and audio format to another and also alter the quality of the output media. The other features that are added are change audio codec, video codec, audio bit rate, video bit rate, audio quality, change volume, set audio channels, change audio sample frequency.
For images, the tools that aviApi provides are smart compression, smart crop, regular crop, resize, fit, trim, rotate and flip. The filters that they provide are greyscale, negate, brighten, sharpen, blur, colorize, contrast, gamma, pixelate and opacity. We also provide some instagram style filters like gotham effect, toaster effect, nashville effect, lomo effect, kelvin effect and tiltshift effect. The API also allows to save one image format to another or encode an image from one format to another. You also have the option to set the quality of the image while saving or encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Kaltura VPaaS (Video Platform as a Service)](https://vpaas.kaltura.com). It is a video hosting service built for developers, API centric with SDKs in many programming languages including; PHP, PHP Namespaces and PHP Zend. It provides video, image and audio transcoding, hosting, processing (transcription, search enrichment, metadata management, etc.), streaming and delivery, distribution, and more. It is used by many large enterprises and global media companies, and features pay-as-you-go pricing for small projects and startups.